# Markdown - Anchor with numbers and spaces

Tags: markdown

I'm trying to create a "table of contents" for my markdown file, having links to the anchors in my file, but the links don't work.

**My title**

```
# 1. Objective
```

**My link to the title**

```
1. [Objective](#1-objective)
```

Is this just not supported?

Comment: By default, Markdown does not create anchors for headers. However, some implementations offer this as an option. Which implementation are you using?

Comment: I was testing in stackedit.io before uploading to bitbucket, which is where I want to display it. I ended up finding the solution for it, I inspected the html elements and found the anchor that bitbucket was generating for title, and used it in my link

Comment: "*I inspected the html elements and found the anchor...*" That's the right way to do it when you don't know the method used. Unfortunately, Bitbucket doesn't document this (see their sparse docs [here](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucketserver/markdown-syntax-guide-776639995.html)), so that really is the only reliable solution.